# How to prevent css grid column from exceeding max-height of the grid container?

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I have a CSS grid layout as follows here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KogEaq

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #222525;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 27fr 78fr;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

#left {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}

#right {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.box {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: blue solid 2px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="box">
      Navigation sidebar stuff here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="box">
      Page content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The page is intended to be a single page app and the body should not scroll. **When the page content becomes large, I wish for the contents in the `.box` class to scroll.**

The problem is, the `.box` and the parent `#right` column within the `#container` grid seem to exceed the max-height set by the container of `100vh`, therefore the `overflow` property of the `.box` is not triggered and the content is cut short.

**Edit:**
If I wasn't clear before, the problem is that **the `.box` and the `#right` elements do not respect the `max-height` attribute of the parent `#container`** which is causing the scroll issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't really the `max-height`. It's the top and bottom margins on your `.box` element (`margin: 8px`). When added to the `max-height: 100vh`, it results in an overflow of the wrong container. If you remove those margins, and add `box-sizing: border-box` (to factor in borders and padding), your page and the `overflow` work as intended.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #222525;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 27fr 78fr;
}

#left {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1
}

#right {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.box {
  /* margin: 8px; */
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: aqua solid 5px;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="box">Navigation sidebar stuff here</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
        <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
        <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
        <li>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a solution, try `padding: 8px` on the parent elements (`#right` and `#left`) instead.

Comment: @jai_ you can use `grid-gap:16px;` on `#container` to replace `margin`